# How can I remove all letters after a certain character in a column in Excel?

Tags: excel, function

For example, 
I have a column with email addresses and I want to remove everything before the @ sign and everything after the '.' so I can attain the company names. 
Such as:

```
Emails
loo@yahoo.com
christina@google.com
rachel@espn.com
john@apple.com
ahmed@microsoft.com
```

I want to create a new column that looks like this:

```
Companies
yahoo
google
espn
apple
ahmed
```

What is a function I can use to attain this new column?

Comment: Look at Right, Left, Len, Find. If you search this site you’ll find many examples to help you.

Comment: Shouldn't the last one be `microsoft`

Comment: yes my bad! lost one is microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use Mid and Find functions.

Mid gives you the substring from one text with arguments : text from which to find, start and no. of characters to be extracted.

And find returns the position of character in the word .

Use this formula in A2 cell and A1 cell contains your string

```
=MID(A1,FIND("@",A1)+1,FIND(".",A1)-FIND("@",A1)-1)
```

Comment: This may not work if the email address contains a **.** before the **@**

Comment: Agree.. just updated the formula, Thanks for pointing it out. =MID(A1,FIND("@",A1)+1,FIND(".com",A1)-FIND("@",A1)-1)

Answer (score 3):

with data in **A2**, in **B2** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("@",A2)+1,9999),".com","")
```

[image]

This will work for all emails ending in *.com* and if there are some records that do not have *com* at the end, use:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("@",A1)+1,FIND(".",A1,FIND("@",A1)+1)-(FIND("@",A1)+1))
```

This will handle records like:

```
darth.vader@deathstar.com
```

in which a dot occurs before the **@**

Answer (score 2):

Select the column (or copy it into a new column) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to go to Find & Replace:

1. Find *@ and replace with nothing (keep blank).
2. Find .* and replace with nothing (keep blank).

Here * represents any sequence of characters.